# Split a sentence and group each value by key

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda, pyspark, rdd

I have an input data in below format which I'm trying to split and create a key value pair:

Input:

```
"SQL",1,2,3,4,5
"ORACLE",2,5,6,7
```

Intended data to write into RDD:

```
SQL,1
SQL,2
SQL,3
SQL,4
SQL,5
ORACLE,2
ORACLE,5
ORACLE,6
ORACLE,7
```

I'm trying to create key-value pair using below code which does not work

```
data_rdd = f.zipWithIndex() \
        .map(lambda row: (row[0].replace('"', '').split(',')[0], (dst for dst in row[1:len(row[0])]))) \
        .aggregateByKey([], lambda a, b: a + [b], lambda a, b: a + b)
```

Comment: For each row `s` you can apply: `[(s.split(',')[0].replace('"', ''), i) for i in s.split(',')[1:]]` and get list of pairs-tuples.

Comment: I did try that earlier, I get a row not defined if I'm using command:    data_rdd = f.zipWithIndex() \
        .map(lambda row: (row[0].split(',')[0].replace('"', ''), i) for i in row.split(',')[1:]) \
        .aggregateByKey([], lambda a, b: a + [b], lambda a, b: a + b)

Answer (score 0):

Input data:

```
inp = '''"SQL",1,2,3,4,5
"ORACLE",2,5,6,7'''
```

Code:

```
res = []

for line in inp.splitlines():
    values = line.split(',')
    key = values[0].replace('"', '')
    res.extend((key, v) for v in values[1:])

print(res)
```

Note: It creates a copy of `values` without first element to skip it.

Also you can skip first element by accessing to `values` elements by index:

```
res = []

for line in inp.splitlines():
    values = line.split(',')
    key = values[0].replace('"', '')
    res.extend((key, values[i]) for i in range(1, len(values)))

print(res)
```

Output:

```
[('SQL', '1'), ('SQL', '2'), ('SQL', '3'), ('SQL', '4'), ('SQL', '5'), ('ORACLE', '2'), ('ORACLE', '5'), ('ORACLE', '6'), ('ORACLE', '7')]
```

If you want to collect them into list of strings in format you provided, just replace

```
res.extend((key, v) for v in values[1:])
```

with

```
res.extend('{},{}'.format(key, v) for v in values[1:])
```

Comment: I'm reading the data from file. This is read into RDD f = sc.textFile("data/text.data"). splitlines is not working with rdd. I get an error 'RDD' object has no attribute 'splitlines'

Comment: @KC, I don't know what RDD is. `splitlines()` is method of `str`. I use it to iterate over lines in string. I guess, you kan iterate over lines in file just with `for line in f`. Anyway find a way to read this file line by line and replace `for line in inp.splitlines():` with proper code.

Answer (score 0):

Use **flatMap()**:

```
data_rdd.flatMap(lambda row: [ 
    (k, v) for k, vs in [row.replace('"','').split(',', 1)] for v in vs.split(',')
]).collect() 

#[('SQL', '1'),
# ('SQL', '2'),
# ('SQL', '3'),
# ('SQL', '4'),
# ('SQL', '5'),
# ('ORACLE', '2'),
# ('ORACLE', '5'),
# ('ORACLE', '6'),
# ('ORACLE', '7')]
```

**Where:**

1. `[row.replace('"','').split(',', 1)]` convert a row like `"SQL",1,2,3,4,5` into a list of two elements `SQL` and `1,2,3,4,5`
2. `vs.split(',')` then split the 2nd item into a new list
3. the list comprehension with tuples of (k, v) will then be flattened by `flatMap()`